# jQuery Real Person with only number

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I have been trying to customize the jQuery real person to use only number however it still showing alphabets. Official page : http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html

I tried by hardcoding the variable in `jquery.real.person.js` but the result still the same

```
var ALPHABETIC = '0123456789';
var ALPHANUMERIC ='0123456789';
```

Any workaround that I can follow to achieve what I want ?

Comment: updated answer, you are almost there, just need to modify the DOTS array to contain only numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/realPersonRef.html), you can set the `chars` property:

```
$(selector).realperson({chars: '0123456789'});
```

> The list of characters to generate the challenge from. The pattern for each character is taken from the corresponding position in dots. You can use $.realperson.alphabetic or $.realperson.alphanumeric for the standard character sequences.

**EDIT**

So I looked into this a bit more and chars doesnt work as expected. It just counts the number of characters you selected and maps that to the DOTS array; so if you do `$(selector).realperson({chars: '9'});`, 'A' will be the only letter in the test string. As a hack, I would suggest, removing the first 26 entries in DOTS (a-z) and doing as you described in the question